# twitter-bootstrap dropdown-toggle opened on display and doesn't toggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inserted a test toggle button ( pasted from demo)

```
#menu1.dropdown
%a.dropdown-toggle{:'data-toggle' => "dropdown", :href => "#menu1"}
    Options
    %b.caret
%ul.dropdown-menu
    %li
        = link_to "Action", "#"
    %li
        = link_to "Another action", "#"
    %li
        = link_to "Something else here", "#"
    %li.divider
    %li
        = link_to "Separated link", "#"
```

The button is displayed but all options are visible and no toggle happen at all

The button-toggle.js plugin is present ( checked in assets ) and I already added  into my application js file

```
$(document).ready ->
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
```

It's very strange  , because at the top of my page , in the navigation bar , I already have a dropdown button to select the site language ... and this one is working fine ... ( displaying both the languages and flags )

```
.btn-group{:style => "margin-top: 4px; float:right;"}
%a.btn{:'data-toggle' => "dropdown", :href => "#", :id => "babLocaleSelect"}
    %span.babFlag{:class => "babFlag-#{I18n.locale}"}= I18n.locale.to_s
    = I18n.t(I18n.locale)

%a.btn.dropdown-toggle{:'data-toggle' => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
    %span.caret

%ul.dropdown-menu.bablevel-content
    - other_backoffice_languages.each do |language|
        %li.babLocale
            %a{:href => backoffice_language_path(:locale => language), :id => "#{language}_language_link"  }
                %span.babFlag{:class => "babFlag-#{language}"}= I18n.t(language)
                = I18n.t(language.to_sym)
```

I tried also to debug , inserting

```
  $(".dropdown-menu").click (event) ->
     alert 'dd clicked'
```

this is triggered by BOTH menus so it's installed but the second is open and never toggle

Comment: Can you post the wrapper for the drop-down menu? That's the `ul` and it's `li`.

Comment: which one ? the language/flags ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing related to Twitter-bootstrap ..

I tried to move the toggle-button in other places of my template , first in my top nav bar as the first one is running, and this test runs well... 
I place it in another part of the template , same results : it runs ...

so I looked into the class used for this button  :  .pagination , which is the class also used  by Kaminari paginator ...  I get rid of this class ... and it runs !!